# How do I roll a column value down starting at a dynamically selected row, by group?

Tags: r, data.table

This code generates a small approximation of my dataset.

```
library(data.table)

stocks <- c("SPY","IBM","GOOG","ISRG")
dates <- seq(as.Date("2012-01-01"), by = "day", length.out = 10)
position <- 0
dt <- data.table()
for(i in 1:4){
    tmp <- data.table(stock = stocks[i], date = dates, position = position)
    dt <- rbind(dt,tmp)
}
```

In my dataset which is > 50GB, these initial positions and dates are set programmatically in one line via subsetting. The code below
just gives and example of what the larger set looks like prior to the desired solution.

```
dt[stock == "SPY" & date == dates[4], position := 5]
dt[stock == "IBM" & date == dates[6], position := 10]
dt[stock == "GOOG" & date == dates[7], position := -10]
dt[stock == "ISRG" & date == dates[3], position := -8]
```

This achieves the desired outcome, but not in a practical way
for the larger dataset.

```
dt[stock == "SPY" & date > dates[4], position := 5]
dt[stock == "IBM" & date > dates[6], position := 10]
dt[stock == "GOOG" & date > dates[7], position := -10]
dt[stock == "ISRG" & date > dates[3], position := -8]
```

The desired solution would perform the task by subsetting to dates > the first date where the position is not equal to zero, while grouping by stock.

Comment: I think you can create a key/value dataset and then do a join

Comment: I think this is possible using joins, but how do I reference the dates for each stock which are only greater than the date where a position is not equal to zero? ie 2012-01-04 / 2012-01-10 for SPY and 2012-01-06 / 2012-01-10 for IBM.

Comment: In the non-equi joins, it is possible, i.e. `dt[newdt, position := pos, on = .(stock, date > dates), by = .EACHI]` where `pos` and `dates` are the columns in the 'newdt' key/value data

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do it:

```
library(nlme)
find.pos<-function(dt){
   initial<-subset(dt, position !=0)
   dt$position<-ifelse(dt$date>initial$date,initial$position,dt$position)
   return(dt)
}

Revised.df<-do.call(rbind.data.frame, gapply(dt, groups=dt$stock, FUN=find.pos))
```